DH Encrypt by XOR
I'm working in the Curve25519 domain (EC curve, 256-bit key size).
I have a peer pubkey, and need to send it an encrypted message.
For starters we create a "nonce" (ephemeral key), and use it to derive a DH shared secret.
Then it's usually used to initialize a symmetric key (i.e. AES or similar) to encrypt the actual message.
But my message is only 256-bit size (yet another key), and I don't need things like HMAC. So I thought about just XOR-ing the key with the shared secret.
Is this scheme good enough?
If I'm not mistaken, the DH shared secret is actually an X-coordinate of the EC point (in affine coordinates). And, strictly speaking, not all values are possible (little less than half actually). But this seems to be a minor consideration.

Some observations:

Curve25519 is only 255 bits effective. The top bit is always 0, so you leak 1 bit of secret.

Elliptic-curve point coordinate is not uniformly distributed, which means there's bias when XOR with the cipher transcript.



Did you forget that 3 bits are zeroed?

Running the shared secret through a hash function like SHA-256 first should fix both of those issues, right?

@n-l-i ECDH security when no KDF is used

@kelalaka the 3 cleared bits are that of the private key, i.e. the scalar. Which means there's still a brutal-force complexity of more than 128 bits.

Pollard's lambda for range queries?

@kelalaka I forgot to mention, the brutal-force is on the scalar, which is about $2^{252.0}$; Pollard's rho on the public key of X25519 takes the much lesser $2^{128.0}$. (note the decimal place for rounding errors)
